# Project from a collection to a dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I am trying to use AutoMapper to convert a collection on an entity to a dictionary. This works when I use the Map function, but it is throwing an exception when I use the queryable extension ProjectTo.

I've created a reproducible example below (usually the ProjectTo would be applied to an EF Core queryable, but in this example, I have just created the Queryable from a list - the resulting exceptions are the same).

```
using AutoMapper;
using AutoMapper.QueryableExtensions;

var cfg = new MapperConfiguration(config =>
{
    config.CreateMap<ParentItem, ParentItemDTO>()
        .ForMember(d => d.ChildItems,
                   o => o.MapFrom(src => src.ChildItems.ToDictionary(key => key.ChildId, value => value)));
    
    config.CreateMap<ChildItem, ChildItemDTO>();
    
    // I have tried adding this and it does not resolve it - throws a different exception
    //config.CreateMap<KeyValuePair<string, ChildItem>, KeyValuePair<string, ChildItemDTO>>();
});
var mapper = new Mapper(cfg);

var parent = new ParentItem
{
    ParentId = "1",
    ChildItems = new List<ChildItem>() {
            new ChildItem() { ChildId = "1", Name = "Child 1" },
            new ChildItem() { ChildId = "2", Name = "Child 2" }
        }
};

var singleResult = mapper.Map<ParentItem, ParentItemDTO>(parent);

var parentQueryable = (new List<ParentItem>() { parent }).AsQueryable();

// This line fails
var projectionResult = parentQueryable.ProjectTo<ParentItemDTO>(mapper.ConfigurationProvider);
        
public class ParentItem
{
    public string ParentId { get; set; }
    public List<ChildItem> ChildItems { get; set; }
}

public class ChildItem
{
    public string ChildId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ParentItemDTO
{
    public string ParentId { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, ChildItemDTO> ChildItems { get; set; }
}

public class ChildItemDTO
{
    public string ChildId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

This successfully works for the single result, but when it hits the ProjectTo line, it will throw the following exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException
  HResult=0x80131509
  Message=Missing map from System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[System.String,ChildItem] to System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[System.String,ChildItemDTO]. Create using CreateMap<KeyValuePair`2, KeyValuePair`2>.
```

I have tried adding a KeyValuePair mapping (commented out in the code above), but then it will just throw a different exception:

```
System.ArgumentException: 'Argument types do not match'
```

Does anyone know if it's possible to use ProjectTo to map from a collection member to a dictionary member like this? Is there something wrong with my approach, or is this a bug/limitation with AutoMapper?

I am using AutoMapper 11.0.1 and .Net 6.

Comment: Try it first with LINQ, without AM.

Comment: Thanks @LucianBargaoanu, but this is an AutoMapper question. Of course it can be done using linq, and it can be done using AutoMapper's Map as well, but I'm specifically interested in knowing whether this can be done using AutoMapper and ProjectTo.

Comment: AM has nothing to do with this question, _unless_ you can do that with a LINQ query, so show us an EF query that works.

Comment: Can you explain why AM has nothing to do with it? I'm grateful you're trying to help, but your posts aren't really providing me with any information.

`var projectionLinq = parentQueryable.Select(m => new ParentItemDTO() { ParentId = m.ParentId, ChildItems = m.ChildItems.ToDictionary(key => key.ChildId, value => new ChildItemDTO() { ChildId = value.ChildId, Name = value.Name }) });`

Sorry - have also just realised you asked for a query - have done a lambda statement - can do it as a linq query, but would prefer to know why. AM is throwing an exception, so it has a lot to do with it.

Comment: Sorry, not sure how to format in this:

`var linq = from n in parentQueryable
   select new ParentItemDTO()
   {
    ParentId = n.ParentId,
    ChildItems = n.ChildItems.ToDictionary(
    k => k.ChildId,
    v => new ChildItemDTO() {
     ChildId = v.ChildId,
     Name = v.Name
    })
   };`

Comment: Again, I asked for a _working_ query. I don't see how that could possibly work. Did you test the query against your db? Because playing with in memory data is completely missing the point of what you're trying to do here.

Comment: Ok, the following is working against a db (parents is: `dbContext.Set<Parent>().AsQueryable()`):
`var parentDTOs = parents.Select(m => new ParentItemDTO()
{
 ParentId = m.ParentId,
 ChildItems = new Dictionary<string, ChildItemDTO>(m.Children.Select(c => new KeyValuePair<string, ChildItemDTO>(c.ChildId, new ChildItemDTO() { ChildId = c.ChildId, Name = c.Description })))
}).ToList();`

Comment: `CreateMap<ChildItem, KeyValuePair<string, ChildItemDTO>>.ConvertUsing(c => new KeyValuePair<string, ChildItemDTO>(c.ChildId, new ChildItemDTO() { ChildId = c.ChildId, Name = c.Description }))` works with the [MyGet build](https://myget.org/feed/automapperdev/package/nuget/AutoMapper). For your version, try a map to `Dictionary.`

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu - Thank you! It works for me using 1) the myget version, 2) the correct linq for a dictionary and 3) the following mappings:
`config.CreateMap<Parent, ParentItemDTO>().ForMember(dest => dest.ChildItems, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Children.Select(c => new KeyValuePair<string, Child>(c.ChildId, c))));` /  
`config.CreateMap<Child, ChildItemDTO>().ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Description));` / 
`config.CreateMap<KeyValuePair<string, Child>, KeyValuePair<string, ChildItemDTO>>();` If you want to post an answer, happy to mark it correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CreateMap<ChildItem, KeyValuePair<string, ChildItemDTO>>.ConvertUsing(c => new KeyValuePair<string, ChildItemDTO>(c.ChildId, new ChildItemDTO() { ChildId = c.ChildId, Name = c.Description }))
```

works with the MyGet build. For your version, try a map to `Dictionary`.